# Connection of different SE accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I first created a Mathematics.SE account, then I created a AskUbuntu.SE account, and the two were connected just fine to my actual "Carlster" account.

When I added Physics (and Meta) the two were linked to a new account - although I used the same e-mail adress to log in.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you use the same OpenID credential (Google, Facebook, etc)?

Comment: Yes! My gmail-adress.

Comment: Just to clarify, you created both accounts by clicking on "Google" on the page asking for OpenID?  You can also give an email address when registering an account, but that's different from your *OpenID login*.  (I know it's confusing, because Google is both a credential and an email address.)  Is it possible that for one account you used Google OpenID and for the other you used something else (like Facebook, Yahoo, your blog, or whatever else is on that list)?

Comment: By the way, your question asks why this happened, but if your goal is really to just get it fixed, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site to ask that the accounts be merged.  Give them both profile links and say which one you want to be the single account going forward.  (You'll need to prove you own both accounts; they'll tell you what to do there.)

Comment: I tried that, but it tells me to give them another meta account. I only have one and can't create another, since the email is already used (by me!). And for the previous question: I only ever used my only gmail adress.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Stack Exchange and they helped me. All my accounts are under one roof now. @Monica Cellio thank you for your effort.

I used Stack Exchange instead of Gmail to sign up for a new SE, and it seemed to solve the problem.

**But** after what Billy Mailman said in the comments to my answer, that should not be the problem.

Comment: FYI: Using the Stack Exchange option, is still using OpenID. Stack Exchange just happens to be an OpenID provider themselves, on top of being a site that uses OpenID for sign-in.

Comment: Then there must be a difference between using an external and the proprietary Open-ID - or not?

Comment: Not really, no. That's kind of the point of OpenID; it really doesn't (at least, shouldn't) matter where you're signing in, or who you're trusting to sign you in.

Comment: ( *you might want to click on the green check mark next to this answer if it's what worked for you in the end, like you said it did* )

Answer (score 3):

I want to emphasize something that appears to have been failed to be communicated in comments.

You were asked:

> Just to clarify, you created both accounts by clicking on "Google" on the page asking for OpenID? You can also give an email address when registering an account, but that's different from your OpenID login. (I know it's confusing, because Google is both a credential and an email address.) Is it possible that for one account you used Google OpenID and for the other you used something else (like Facebook, Yahoo, your blog, or whatever else is on that list)?

To which you responded:

> And for the previous question: I only ever used my only gmail adress.

Your address *is not the issue here.* The question is really...

[image: Did you use your email address to sign in with Google or Stack Exchange?]

Your *actual email address* is beside the point. You can create an account with Google using your gmail address, and you can create an account with Stack Exchange using your gmail address. But even if you use the same email address, *these will be two different accounts*, because they are from different providers: Google vs Stack Exchange.

When you were asked in comments what you used to sign in, you were being asked whether you signed in with *Google* (as in the "Sign up using Google" option above) or something else, not whether you used your gmail address.

To avoid creating new accounts, make sure you use *the same provider*, *as well as* the same account on that provider.

Comment: I always pressed "Sign up using Google". Additionally I made sure that I am the one logged in on Google, and not a friend of mine from who's laptop I often access the Internet. (Could the different IP be the cause?)

Comment: Here's the chronology: 1) Signed up for Mathematics with Google, created "Carlster" account. 2) Signed up for SO and German the same way (first button) with the same address - profile still says "Carlster". 3) Signed up for Chess and Meta the very same way again, and suddenly I'm user3060...

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's the information that was being sought.